# Can Anyone help me with this ranking in php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table like below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cxexam` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`regd` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Name_of_Student` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`Class` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`Roll_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Section` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`Name_of_exam` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`Test_date` date NOT NULL,
`Subject` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`Full_mark` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Mark_score` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Year` year(4) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `cxexam`

```
INSERT INTO `cxexam` (`id`, `regd`, `Name_of_Student`, `Class`, `Roll_no`, `Section`, `Name_of_exam`, `Test_date`, `Subject`, `Full_mark`, `Mark_score`, `Year`) VALUES

(6, 20, 'Ramdina', 'X', 9, 'A', 'Second Term Unit Test', '2013-07-19', 'English', 20, 18, 2013),
(3, 2, 'Zonundanga', 'X', 5, 'A', 'Second Term Unit Test', '2013-07-19', 'English',   20, 12, 2013),
(4, 40, 'Lalnunkimi', 'X', 10, 'A', 'Second Term Unit Test', '2013-07-19', 'English', 20, 18, 2013);
```

the mysql query will produce:

```
regd   totalscore    rank
20   18   1
2   18   1
40  12   2
```

And I want to output rank of whose `regd='2'` using php. I am using the following php code and mysql code but I need to refresh my page to get the code working. The query is working fine in phpmyadmin, but most of the times I got only `1` as rank even when I change the `regd`.

```
mysql_select_db($database_dbconnect, $dbconnect);
$query_myrank = "SELECT Distinct regd, Test_date, Year, Name_of_Student, TOTALSCORE,  Rank FROM 
(SELECT *, IF(@marks = (@marks := TOTALSCORE), @auto, @auto := @auto + 1) AS
Rank FROM (SELECT Name_of_Student, regd, Test_date, Year, SUM(Mark_score) AS TOTALSCORE 
FROM cxexam, (SELECT @auto := 0, @marks := 0) AS init GROUP BY regd, Year ORDER BY TOTALSCORE DESC) t) AS result HAVING regd='2' and Year='2013' and Test_date between '2013-07-01' and '2013-07-30'";
$myrank = mysql_query($query_myrank, $dbconnect) or die(mysql_error());
$row_myrank = mysql_fetch_assoc($myrank);
$Rank= $row_myrank['Rank'];
```

I echo it using `<?php echo $row_myrank['Rank'];?>` I would be very happy if anyone can get me an alternative solution using php because I am trying to apply this ranking in my school marksheet management system.

This is my new code:

```
<?php 
mysql_select_db($database_dbconnect, $dbconnect);
$query_myrank = "SELECT Distinct regd, Test_date, Year, Name_of_Student, TOTALSCORE, Rank 
FROM (SELECT *, IF(@marks = (@marks := TOTALSCORE), @auto, @auto := @auto + 1) AS Rank 
FROM (SELECT Name_of_Student, regd, Test_date, Year, SUM(Mark_score) AS TOTALSCORE 
FROM cxexam, (SELECT @auto := 0, @marks := 0) AS init GROUP BY regd, Year ORDER BY TOTALSCORE DESC) t) AS result HAVING Year='$yr' and Test_date between '$fdate' and '$tdate'";
$myrank = mysql_query($query_myrank, $dbconnect) or die(mysql_error());

$i = 0;
$j = 1;
$data = array();
while($row_myrank = mysql_fetch_assoc($myrank))
{
$data[$i] = $row_myrank;
if(isset($data[$i - 1]) && $data[$i - 1]['TOTALSCORE'] == $data[$i]['TOTALSCORE'])
{
   $data[$i]['Rank'] = $j;
}else{
   $data[$i]['Rank'] = ++$j;
}
   $i++;
}
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
if($value['regd'] == $regd)
{
echo $value['Rank'];
}
}
?>
```

Comment: @David Level No, regd is not a unique column..

Comment: Why don't you just do a SELECT  * FROM my_table WHERE regd = 2?

Comment: No it's not in you schema you did not add the constraint and when I readed again your question I just figured out that this column could not be unique. Or maybe I didn't understand?

Comment: @David level I have to look up rank ties also and do not know how to do rank ties in php

Comment: Add an order statement so It will sort it for you

Comment: @David Level you can see an `Order' statement in my query.

Comment: Sorry I just got your problem I post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the loop add an automatic increment like this.

```
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;

$data = array();

    while($row_myrank = mysql_fetch_assoc($myrank))
    {
      $data[$i] = $row_myrank;
      if(isset($data[$i - 1]) && $data[$i - 1]['Mark_Score'] == $data[$i]['Mark_Score'])
      {
       $data[$i]['rank'] = $j;
      }else{
       $data[$i]['rank'] = ++$j;
      }
      $i++;
    }
```

It would be a bad answer if don't say "Don't use mysql_* function but PDO". Look at this link please. http://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.pdo.php

EDIT: How to output data

```
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
 if($value['regd'] == 2)
 {
   echo $value['field'];
 }
}
```

Just change field by the ones in your query.

Comment: This is outputing all the rows, I just want to output only one row `where regd='2'` also it does not calculate ties in rank.

Comment: please can you show me the echo statement for this, I am just a beginner.

Comment: Look at my edit for the rank. I try to figure out your first comment

Comment: If I understand well you want to rank all and after you output the one with reg = 2? So you can loop over the $data table and add a if statement

Comment: It does not output anything. thanks for your patience. I am using the same query.

Comment: No it don't because it just store data ranked inside the array. I though you'd know how to make the echo

Comment: This is a little more complex for me. can you show me the whole code. I don't find `echo` or `print` in your code.

Comment: I could not figure out where to use echo..please put it here...thank you very much.

Comment: I will test and let you know.

Comment: You should try to adapt to understand how it works. I can't do all the debug because I don't have all data in front of me

Comment: I still don't get anything output..I add my whole code in the post. please debug and give me the solution. I really need this. I am working for three days to get it work now.

Comment: I can't chat with you so please give me link where I can get the code and a dump of the database. BecauseI need to see how you use my code

Comment: And I edit the code, didn't see that regd was an integer and not a string but if you had test it you could see it by yourself I guess

Comment: `regd` is an integer. Please look at the post.

Comment: I changed it but I'll try something. Show me somewhere the update you did with my answer. Maybe you don't use it well

Comment: You are right I am a newbie.  I have posted the whole code I am using under the question. If you scroll up you will see just above my first comment.

Comment: Yes I found it. Some vars are not in your code. Why? Just echo $query_mark, I'll use the query to do the PHP code because I guess the query works

Comment: I have changed `Mark_score` to `TOTALSCORE` and `'$regd'` to `$regd` in the echo. It almost works well. problem is that I have three rows with two ranks as two student get the same rank, your code does not output 1st rank. It goes like 2 for the two students who get the same rank 3 rank for the third student.

Comment: Please just add here the sql query output I'll test it on my own server. I can't figure out the code without testing it

Comment: this is the query:  `SELECT Distinct regd, Test_date, Year, Name_of_Student, TOTALSCORE, Rank 
FROM (SELECT *, IF(@marks = (@marks := TOTALSCORE), @auto, @auto := @auto + 1) AS Rank 
FROM (SELECT Name_of_Student, regd, Test_date, Year, SUM(Mark_score) AS TOTALSCORE 
FROM cxexam, (SELECT @auto := 0, @marks := 0) AS init GROUP BY regd, Year ORDER BY TOTALSCORE DESC) t) AS result HAVING Year='$yr' and Test_date between '$fdate' and '$tdate'`

Comment: No I mean echo it so I won't need to define $fdate, ... It will output the query you send to mysql

Comment: Thanks a million for your time. You are so helping. I could find the solution now...I have just just `$j=1` to `$j=0` and it works like a charm. Thank you thank you very much.

Comment: Ho nice :). Don't forget to solve it. And don't forget to use PDO instead of mysql_* in your next script

Comment: I highly appreciate your work. so I would like to share you my marksheet that I upload in image hosting http://postimg.org/image/7dt7xx59p/18df9f91/..

Comment: Is that the final app?

Comment: Yes, this is the final.

Comment: That's nice to see the final work. Thanks for that :) I really appreciate